# Why didn't they harvest more genetic information?

Tags: neal-stephenson

In [*Seveneves* by Neal Stephenson](http://www.nealstephenson.com/seveneves.html), towards the end of part II, the human race is reduced to 7 people (all women) who contrive to rebuild the human race by use of [parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis#Humans). Due to various mishaps (and the uninvited and unwelcome US president) the pre-prepared 'Human Genetic Archive' has been destroyed so only the genetic material from the 7 remains.

They knew, before the population was reduced to 7, that the archive had been destroyed. So why didn't they 'harvest' genetic information from *everyone* who was still alive at this point ?

Comment: I would prefer that these questions stay on the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange. See [thoughts on “why didn't character x act rationally” questions?](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/91/111).

Comment: I was really hoping for a scientific explanation of why this didn't happen. I suspect that Neal Stephenson, being the thorough author that he is wouldn't be satisfied with 'they didn't think about it' as a plausible answer. In my opinion there's probably some solid science behind this question that I don't (yet) understand.

Comment: Wasn't the archive more of a publicity stunt than an actual resource?

Comment: If you're looking for a scientific explanation (i.e. an explanation not based on the text but based on modern science), then I would be inclined to close this question as off topic. We're a site about literature, not science.

Comment: It likely has to do with the state of Moira's equipment, the background radiation, etc.  (I'm not formally posting an answer b/c this is really a question for Sci-fi.  An example of a Lit site question might be "Can orbital mechanics be said to be the central theme of Seveneves?"

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained earlier - I've put this question on hold for now, because I think it needs editing to be workably answerable on this site. I'm hardly the final say in close voting, but would it be possible for you to edit this question to address some of the concerns of the commenters here?

Comment: I haven't read this book, but I can't really see anything wrong with this question as it stands. It *may* not be answerable, but it's hard to prove a negative, and "we don't know" could be a perfectly valid answer. Voting to reopen. @Emrakul What do you mean by "workably answerable", and what *sort* of editing does it need? Constructive criticism please! :-)

Comment: I have no doubt the author could provide a direct answer, as the question was surely considered in the crafting of the plot.  The reason I won't give a formal answer here is this question doesn't relate to theme or any of the literary elements in the book, but relates to an in-universe explanation (minutiae) of a genre for which such a forum, Sci-Fi, already exists.   If I see the question on Sci Fi, I would gladly provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either Stephenson didn't consider this, or considered it and turned it down. This is ultimately good: Stephenson's role as an author is to remain scientifically plausible under benefit of the doubt in order to play emotional appeals, not to maintain strict adherence to scientific and logical accuracy.

Stephenson as an author regularly puts on the facade of scientific possibility. He does this in order to make the events in a story seem reasonable and plausible - but make no mistake, it's just a facade. The entire point about the moon breaking up is a great monument to the pseudoplausibility he employs. His position as an author, and where he places himself, is emotional appeal to the scientific mind.

So, the framing of this question somewhat misses the point of that part of the story. It's not intended to be a scientific or wholly rationalized approach - it's intended to be a good yarn, a story consumed and a story pushing towards something on a more emotional level.

And at the end of it, there's an enormous amount of emotional draw in the idea of seven people embarking to restore the human race on Earth. It's a task that Stephenson is setting up to seem *plausible but difficult*, with no mind to issues such as "we need greater biodiversity than that to succeed." Consider, then, what would be different if Stephenson had done it the way you propose here: that emotional draw would have been lost, because the future of humanity would be a heck of a lot more certain and guaranteed.

It wouldn't be more certain in reality, mind you, but setting it up so that the one resource needed to rebuild humanity was destroyed is an operative point in that emotional appeal.